# Is DL360 G8 w/ P822 w/ internal 12x3,5" cage suitable for ZFS backup machine?

Tags: zfs

I know there was similiar post but it was more about external disc enclosure.
[Smart Array P822 with HBA Mode?](https://serverfault.com/questions/874706/smart-array-p822-with-hba-mode)
I would like to use internal 12x3,5" cage of the DL360g8.
If P822 8i RAID card in HBA a mode connected to the expander of the cage, which is also 8i ( I assume as this server is comaptible with that card), is that OK for ZFS? What about those "internal expanders" of P822 user @ewwhite mentioned in the linked thread?

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to use a P822 on a server like that. Is there anything wrong with the internal P420i controller?

The P420i controller will work very well in HBA mode if you're using SAS disks. 
If you use SATA drives, you're better off using multiple RAID0 groups. This is specific to the onboard controller.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with P420i. Its just this server is shipped with P822. I will use SATA disks. This is storage backup server only. Should there be as few hardware layers as possible presented to the ZFS? Can you elaborate more why RAID0 groups for SATA disks? I understand that you create that many RAID0 groups consisting of a single drive each how many total drives there are. What when the server fails and I will want to move the drives to another machine and recover data? Edit: I think DL360 G8 servers have B120i controller

Comment: DL360p or DL360e?

Comment: Actually, DL380's are the only systems with 12 x 3.5" bays. Can you provide the actual server model?

Comment: my bad - DL380e G8 12x3,5 w/P822 - I might use SAS drives if thats better for ZFS, dataintegrity, etc. I would prefer SATA as they are cheaper, especially at higher capacities, and this is only backup

Comment: so  a DL380e will have "onboard" P420i and P822? This question is based on your previous input.

Comment: There's no high-end controller on that model (DL380e Gen8) by default. See the HP Quickspecs: https://h20195.www2.hpe.com/v2/getdocument.aspx?docname=c04128166 - You will want to add a proper adapter. The Smart Array or an HBA are fine.